# Next 14: The page file is not reacting to anything

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to the Next 14, last time I used it was in version 12. I tried to create pages with the app directory, in the layout file I defined a Navbar, which does the job correctly, but as I'm working on the children of the layout file, the passed children is not reacting to anything. The links are not working and the css hover effects is what I noticed. I did not find any information about that in the documentation that I should do anything with the page.tsx files. Is there any additional configuration that I should do? I tried putting "use client" in the top of the page.tsx file but it doesn't did anything.

This is my layout.tsx file:

```
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import { Righteous } from "next/font/google";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Endor Design",
  description:
    "Endor Design Logózás Ajándéktárgyak Weboldal készítés Marketing videók",
};
const righteous = Righteous({ weight: "400" });
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The NavBar Links and animations are working correctly. The Home page would be too long to paste it here.

This is my
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVgmZ.png)

And this is my page.tsx. I tried to interact in this page without nesting other component, but this also doesn't work.

```
import Gift from "@/components/home/Gift";
import Profile from "@/components/home/Profile";
import Welcome from "@/components/home/Welcome";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <Welcome />
      <Profile />
      <Gift />
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The implementation of RootLayout is correct. Can you share me your folder structure and a page file?

Comment: I added these infos to the post

Comment: When you navigate to the root path (ex: http://localhost:3000/ ), you should see the HomePage.

Comment: Yes, I see it, but as I try to interact with the page like hovering on content or clicking on links it doesn't give any interaction back

Answer (score 0):

From Next 13, all the pages with a path should be listed in `app` folder and named `page.tsx`.

Please check [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) for defining routes.

Comment: This is not my problem, I did it correctly, these components what I show is in other folder named components